# Transferring iPhone message history to new Mac?

Tags: messages, high-sierra, ios

My filesystem was corrupted when updating to High Sierra so I wiped it and restored my files from a dropbox backup. However, I didn't back up my iMessages because I thought I could easily restore them through iCloud. Since Apple removed the iCloud message history synchronization feature after the iOS 11 and High Sierra beta period, is there currently a way to transfer my past messages from my iPhone to my laptop and view them within the Messages app?

All of the third-party solutions I've found so far export iPhone iMessages to pdf or csv files rather than the archive format used by Messages on MacOS.

Answer (score 2):

did you make backups of the iPhone on the mac (with iTunes or iMazing):
if so you can easily restore the messages from the backup.

Comment: Yes I did, but how can I restore the backup such that I can see historical messages within the Messages app in MacOS? The iPhone backup contains a bunch of hashed filenames and nothing that looks like files I can drag to `~/Library/Messages/`. Am I missing something obvious?